# Total format and clean start of Win10/Ubuntu/Kali tri-boot hdd?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, format

Here's the question: Windows is inaccessible, but Ubuntu works. How do I totally format every OS and every partition on my hard drive? I want to wipe the slate and return it to factory condition.

Here's the background: when I boot into Windows on my laptop, it presents with all the classic symptoms of a failing hard drive. Started with long loading times, progressed to random system crashes, and now it's reached the dreaded Automatic Repair boot-up loop. However, Ubuntu and Kali work fine (afaict). It's less than a year old, but I haven't exactly been gentle with it.

So I want to format and reconsolidate every partition, reinstall win10, and figure out whether there's really an HDD failure, or if it's an issue I created myself when setting up the laptop.

I'm sorry if this question has already been answered; I really didn't know how or what to search for to find the solution. If it has, I totally get it if you chastise or flame me, but I'd really appreciate at least a link to the answer. Thanks (and/or sorry)!

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to delete everything and want to fresh start!

Do as follows:

- Download ubuntu and make a bootable USB drive.
- Boot your system with your bootable USB.
- Then click on ‘Try Ubuntu'
- Now search for a program `gparted` Install if not available.

  `sudo apt-get install gparted`
- Now, run `gparted`.
- you must be greeted with list of partitions.
- Delete all the partitions.
- And now create new partitions as you needed, like you may want to create three separate partition for your triple booting.

Now you can install ubuntu first cause you don't have any OS in your laptop now, So it will be good to have one in first place and you don't need to do any preparation for installing ubuntu
or if you want to install any other OS first then it is your choice.